# Floating an image down inside a div with css?

Tags: css, image, css-float

For a blog im doing ive asigned a css class to every second post. I wanted to use the class for making every other postthumbnail/bodytext change places. The image is in top with at width of 100%, and would like it in the bottom?
Can it be done with CSS?
What would you do?

all help is appreciated! :)

Comment: So in the markup you have basically `<img>` and than a `<p>` you just want the image to be under the `p` every second element?

Comment: jsfiddle, snapshot or code????

Answer (score 0):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/zj43Z/

```
.post.odd  .postthumbnail.bottom ,
.post.even .postthumbnail.top  { display: none; }
```

Uses the image on top and on bottom and hides the one that is not needed.